# Reading a file into three different vectors in C++

Tags: c++

I have a space delimted file which look slike tis:

```
4 55 -1.8
4 61 -1.8
2 37 -1.56739
9 1 -1.23
29 8 -1.918
4 57 -1.2
54 63 -1.118012
```

I wrote the following code to read it line by line into the vetors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> row1 = {};
    std::vector<int> row2 = {};
    std::vector<double> row3 = {};

    int row1val, row2val;
    double row3val;

    std::string line;
    // read input a line at a time until end-of-file
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::cin >> row1val >> row2val >> row3val;
        row1.push_back(row1val);
        row2.push_back(row2val);
        row3.push_back(row3val);
    }

    std::cout << row1[0] << " " << row2[0] << " " << row3[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think there are a number of issues:

1) The first row of data is not stored in the vector.

2) The code looks very inelegant like using`line` and variable s `row1val` etc. . Is there a way to simplify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from `std::cin` alternatively by calling `getline()` and by using formatted input. You probably want to stick to one or the other.

```
while (std::cin >> row1val >> row2val >> row3val)
{
    row1.push_back(row1val);
    row2.push_back(row2val);
    row3.push_back(row3val);
}
```

The risk in this one is that it will accept lines that are shorter or longer than three elements, "stealing" elements from the next line.

To avoid that risk, you can just use `getline()` to read from `cin`, and then parse the resulting buffer:

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream linebuf(line);
    if( linebuf >> row1val >> row2val >> row3val) {
        row1.push_back(row1val);
        row2.push_back(row2val);
        row3.push_back(row3val);
    }
}
```

### EDIT

To avoid the temporary variables and the repetition of `row1val`, etc, you could create a class, and store your data in a single vector of that class, instead of three vectors. Here is a complete sample program. Note that it includes both the `getline()`-based and formatted-input-based solutions for you to choose from.

Regardless of which `operator>>` you choose, notice how simple the `main()` function becomes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

struct row_t {
    int row1val, row2val;
    double row3val;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&is, row_t& r) {
#ifdef USE_GETLINE
        std::string line;
        if(std::getline(is, line) &&
           std::istringstream(line) >> r.row1val >> r.row2val >> r.row3val) {
            return is;
        }
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
#else
        return is >> r.row1val >> r.row2val >> r.row3val;
#endif
    };
};

int main() {
    std::vector<row_t> rows((std::istream_iterator<row_t>(std::cin)),
                             std::istream_iterator<row_t>());


    std::cout << rows[0].row1val << " " << rows[0].row2val << " " << rows[0].row3val << std::endl;
    std::cout << rows.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Can something be done about the row1Val variables?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. Perhaps your recent edit to your question will elicit a solution that is more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @Morpheus - On consideration, the way to get DRY is to move parallel data into a class. Consider the edit that I just made to my answer.

Comment: You can maybe abuse `std::back_inserter`.